# Get Physical Folder site is running under

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to get the folder that my website is running under.  I have used many different methods within HttpContext.Current.Request but none of them were returning what I was looking for.  I can easily get the value using substring but it doesn't look very clean and was wondering if there was a shorthand way of getting the folder.

For example when I use the code.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")
```

I get C:\ClientProjects\Dev\v10.3\src\MySite

I can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~").Substring(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~").LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
```

But this seems really bloated way to get the folder I'm running under.

Comment: All the methods I can think of return a path not a directory. So I think your fine with the substring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be able to get the directory name from a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object.

```
Dim info As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~"))
Dim name As String = info.Name ' name will have the value "MySite"
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than what I had thanks for the response.  One small note is that it should be System.IO.DirectoryInfo in case anyone else uses the code but IntelliSense will probably tell you before this comment.